# EAR packaging without EJB in JBoss Seam

Tags: jakarta-ee, seam, ejb, ear, pojo

We started a new project development using seam-gen and selected EAR option because we intended to use EJBs for service layer. But soon we realized that we badly need hot deployment feature so we switched to Seam JavaBeans instead of EJBs. Our packaging remained EAR.

Is it a bad idea to have an EAR packaging knowing that there is no EJB in use (as of now)?
Any advantages/disadvantages that experienced people foresee now?
What can be compelling reasons not to switch to WAR packaging?

Appreciate any response

-Nitin

Answer (score 2):

Hot deployment of EJB's as you stated is not supported out of the box. However, there is a great product called [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) which supports even hot deployment of EJB's.

Its free to try, so check it out.
It takes about [5 minutes to install](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2010/12/how-to-reduce-your-re-deployment.html).

> Is it a bad idea to have an EAR packaging knowing that there is no EJB in use (as of now)? Any advantages/disadvantages that experienced people foresee now? What can be compelling reasons not to switch to WAR packaging?

No of course not.

- Another feature of EAR packaging, is that you can deploy multiple war's inside a WAR. There is no requirement of using EJB's and no downside of not using it.
- You also get extra EJB features which you don't get with Seam. For instance, `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`
- I am sure there are others.